# Trigger webdriver/selenium tests upon a form submit

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, webdriver

I’m struggling to find a solution to an issue I’m facing in setting up an app that will run some simple predefined tests to remove some manual testing from our workflow.

The idea is that you can submit a URL via a simple form then it should run some tests checking for things such as checking for a H1 on the page etc and then print out the results nicely formatted.

Ideally this would be all be done in Node with React or something on top but I’m not too sure how to link the form to the scraper to check the markup of the supplied URL and then return the results of the tests in a web page.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: stackoverflow is not meant to be a code writing service. You should try something on your own and when the code is not working ask a question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also please check out the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section

Answer (score 0):

Try using Jenkins (CI tool). You can configure a job that does all the steps to run the tests, archive the test results, send mail with attachments. You can trigger the build by hitting a URL (job should be configured accordingly for this). Results of the tests can be viewed in the web page by accessing the build URL.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins should fit for your needs and for reporting you can use Allure Test Report, can be integrated very nice with Jenkins.